# Maven SCM Handler for CVS in Eclipse (Juno)

Tags: eclipse, maven, cvs, m2e, eclipse-luna

I'm a longtime Eclipse and Maven user, but am just now upgrading to the more recent Eclipse builds (Luna- 4.4.1).

I've noticed that while Luna ships with m2e (1.5), the m2e marketplace no longer seems to have the 'Maven SCM Handler for CVS' as it did in the past.  Has this handler been discontinued?  Are there any other handlers that would allow for clean integration of Eclipse/Maven/CVS?

Without that handler, importing a Maven project from CVS is a rather painful affair; import generic cvs project, apply java project wizard, convert project to maven project.  Once that's done, you then have to reconfigure other project settings such as Java source, resources, etc.  All of this was automatically handled in m2e 1.0.x with the CVS handler.

Comment: I believe version 4.4.1 is Luna.

Comment: @user944849 You are correct, I made a typo and have now corrected it.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

For CVS SCM connector (if you want to import maven project from cvs repository):
Install new software: http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-cvs/0.13.0/N/0.13.0.201304101743/
More info: [Maven Eclipse (m2e) SCM connector for subclipse 1.10 (svn 1.8)](http://www.buluschek.com/?p=292)
(In case you're wondering, it also worked on Eclipse Mars)

## First solution

How to install the SCM connector:

- download zip [org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip](http://www.buluschek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip) or files from above repository location
- unzip the file to an empty folder somewhere, remember that folder (or put the files from repository in that folder)
- In Eclipse,

  - go to Help/Install New Software…
  - Click “Add…” to add a new site
  - In the window, click on “Local…” and choose the folder where you unzipped the site before. The result in the Location field should look like `file:/C:/theUnzipFolder/`
  - Click OK, choose all available packages to install, and continue the installation as usual

## Second solution

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Install New Software -> Enter above repository location and hit enter
3. Select Maven Integration for Eclipse CVS Team Provider -> Finish

## Alternative solution to SCM connector:

1. Checkout your project in workspace
2. Open cmd.exe and go to project location in that workspace. Then execute the following

   ```
   mvn eclipse:eclipse
   ```
3. Open Eclipse with that workspace path as target
4. Right click in **Project Explorer** panel, Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> Select project location from workspace and you should see the projects in here
5. Right click on your project in **Project Explorer** panel -> Maven -> Update project -> Select all projects -> Ok
6. Don't forget to:

   - set your corresponding JDK in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs
   - set your corresponding compiler level in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Compiler compliance level
   - set JAVA_HOME environment variable